# How can I capture a where clause and use it in a stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a client with many integrations to a SQL Server. All the integrations are doing simple calls such as getting an account name.

Due to migration, the SQL Server is being replaced with a different data source that I can communicate via API.

I've written both OLE and CLR type comms to get the data required, that's the easy part, the problem is that in SQL (SSMS) this is done as a function with a parameter such as `getCustomerName(id)`.

I am, of course, simplifying this for this question but you get the idea.

The issue I have is that the integrations cannot be changed to consume a function with parameter and only do a select, eg. `select name from customer where id = 123`

So my question is this... can I capture the where clause being passed to view so that I can then call the function with that detail and produce a dataset?

Every search I've done focuses on the don't do this, SQL injection etc. etc. instead of the how and ifs, I just want to know if I can capture the where clause and how.

[image]

Comment: If you are using the Management Studio (SSMS), then you are using a script. But then you can simply cut and paste. If you are using a C# CLR class you could send a delegate (like x=> if (whatever) return true). If it's something else please clarify and give code examples.

Comment: thanks for answering but....
if the view query contains something such as this...
select * from getCustomerName(123)
then the view would display the details from that function but the function is specifically stating the id of 123 in the parameter

my question is how can i do a select to this view with a where clause, capture that where clause and use the details in the where to then use in the function call

the integrations can only use select from view where id = x, they cannot call the function, so the view calls the function, i need to capture and use the detail passed into where

Comment: Have you tried this `select dbo.getCustomerName(id) from customer where id = 123`?

Comment: This way it's still a `select` statement and it's also using the view...

Comment: nice, i like that!! but remember, i cannot change the query being posted from the integration, that will be a select x from view where id=y,

Comment: From my knowledge, I don't think you can catch the `where` clause, if you're not able to change the query posted from the integration...

Comment: im not sure its possible either, my memory tells ive seen it done but thats not always reliable

Answer (score 0):

So based on our discussion in the comments, I suggest you get a way to change the query posted from the integration, then use the following:

```
select
    dbo.getCustomerName(id)
from customer
where id = 123
```

This way, you utilize the `view` & `function` simultaneously...

Comment: the integration query cannot be changed